# Redshift query issue - using variable in query

Tags: amazon-redshift

Recently I struct in issue, I am trying to resolve it since a week. I tried every possible solution but no luck.
My procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  schema_check(staging_schemaName IN VARCHAR
                                          ,prod_schemaName IN VARCHAR
                                          ,tblnames IN VARCHAR
                                          , rs_out INOUT refcursor
                                          )
AS
$$
declare
tblname varchar(500);
BEGIN
-- Converting tablename into valid string for in clause
with vars as (
           select trim(''''|| REPLACE(tblnames,'|',''',''')||'''') as tbl
              )
tblname:=(SELECT tbl FROM vars);
RAISE NOTICE 'value of a :%', tblname;  

OPEN rs_out FOR

select 'SELECT (CASE  (SELECT  count(*)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE table_name = '''|| t.table_name ||'''
        AND column_name = '''|| c.column_name ||'''
        AND table_schema ='''|| prod_schemaName ||'''
        AND data_type ='''|| c.data_type ||''')
        when 1 then ''''
      else ''Not present: Schema: '|| prod_schemaName ||' | Table Name: ' || t.table_name || ' | Column Name: '||c.column_name ||' | Column Data Type: '||c.data_type ||''' end) as status union'   as query
from information_schema.tables t
inner join information_schema.columns c 
           on c.table_name = t.table_name 
           and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
where t.table_schema ILIKE staging_schemaName 
      and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
      and c.table_name in ('cart')
order by t.table_schema;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Callable function:

```
BEGIN;
CALL schema_check('dbname', 'prod','table1,table2' ,'cursor_name');
FETCH ALL FROM cursor_name;
CLOSE cursor_name;
```

Error I am getting:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "$2";
```

Here, I am passing tablenames to procedure i.e. "table1,table2". Now, these table names I have to use in "in" clause in where condition if you see my procedure. So, before doing that, I am converting it those table names to 'table1','table2' so that it will be valid statement.

Hope I am able to describe the issue correctly, looking for some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at this procedure, I have done a similar thing to pass multiple values. https://thedataguy.in/redshift-unload-multiple-tables-schema-to-s3/

Comment: @TheDataGuy Looks temporary solution.

Comment: Getting error: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit

Comment: If you have more tables, then this LISTAGG limitation will throw an error, let me see the alternate